# How to restore ubuntu start menu after installed Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu

After I upgraded my Windows XP to Windows 7, I lose the start GRUB menu of ubuntu, how could I restore the GRUB select menu within Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the Ubuntu Live CD to reinstall Grub. It will scan and detect all other OS's and add them to the boot menu. See [the Ubuntu help docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)

Comment: is that possible within windows 7?

Comment: I doubt it, it's testament to Windows not playing too nice with others. I had to do this a while back, I learned a lot from doing it!